# How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to write a Perl script using the `utf8` pragma, and I'm getting unexpected results.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard), and I'm editing with TextMate.  All of my settings for both my editor and operating system are defaulted to writing files in utf-8 format.

However, when I enter the following into a text file, save it as a ".pl", and execute it, I get the friendly "diamond with a question mark" in place of the non-ASCII characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;
use utf8;

my $str = 'Çirçös';
print( "$str\n" );
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I expect to get 'Çirçös' in the output, but I get '�ir��s' instead.

Comment: Maybe its not the program .. i think its your shell oder your editor which does the output

Comment: All answers correctly answer your question how to set it explicitly to UTF8. I think you should be adjust to the locale settings of your terminal as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405949/498634. The terminal might not be set to UTF8 and then data written to STDOUT in UTF8 **will be encoded incorrectly**!

Comment: [Great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/4632019) how to work with `utf8`:

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`use utf8;` does not enable Unicode *output* - it enables you to type Unicode in your program. Add this to the program, before your `print()` statement:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

See if that helps. That should make `STDOUT` output in UTF-8 instead of ordinary ASCII.

Comment: I didn't know about this (I've only been putting UTF8 in a database, never printing it).  +1.

Comment: You're welcome. See also another correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/writing-perl-code-in-utf8/627975#627975 and remember, TMTOWTDI. And @Paul - if you're writing UTF-8 to a file, you should probably use binmode() on that filehandle and make it "proper" UTF-8, but if it works..

Comment: other ways: the open pragma ( http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/open ), the -C switch ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#-C )

Comment: I shy away from the -C switch because not all Perls (i.e. ActivePerl) can process command-line switches well (to my knowledge),

Comment: FWIW here is the reason: strings that contains only latin1 (ISO-8859-1) characters, despite being stored more or less in utf8, will be output as latin1 by default. This way scripts from a pre-unicode era still work the same, even with a unicode-aware perl.

Comment: The utf8 pragma does not let you write your source in UNICODE, it forces understand of your source in the UTF-8 (or UTF-EBCDIC) encoding of UNICODE, an important distinction.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: In my opinion UTF-8 in perl is a _mess_! Sometimes it helps to know that one is not alone. See my post: [Why am I having so much trouble and pain with UTF-8 in perl?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=862973)

Comment: As per Perl 5.8.8, I can't get this working when trying to write Unicode strings into a file (I got warning like "Wide character in print ..."), although others say they did. The open pragma one works.

Answer (score 90):

You can use the [open pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html).

For eg. below sets STDOUT, STDIN & STDERR to use UTF-8....

```
use open qw/:std :utf8/;
```

Comment: BTW... I gave u +1. I think binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8') is probably more correct in this situation.  "use open" has other good uses but I can't seem to find how u can set it to just encode STDOUT only?

Answer (score 82):

[TMTOWTDI](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?tmtowtdi), chose the method that best fits how you work.  I use the environment method so I don't have to think about it.

In the [environment](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL_UNICODE):

```
export PERL_UNICODE=SDL
```

on the [command line](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*):

```
perl -CSDL -le 'print "\x{1815}"';
```

or with [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html):

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");          #treat as if it is UTF-8
binmode(STDIN, ":encoding(utf8)"); #actually check if it is UTF-8
```

or with [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html):

```
open my $fh, ">:utf8", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!\n";

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf-8)", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!\n";
```

or with the [open pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html):

```
use open ":encoding(utf8)";
use open IN => ":encoding(utf8)", OUT => ":utf8";
```

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive answer; note that `SDL` is implied both with `-C` and `PERL_UNICODE`. The `use open ':locale'` pragma is also worth mentioning, because it is the in-script equivalent of `-C` and `export PER_UNICODE=`. Any of these 3 will give you UTF8 support for all input and output streams (whether files or stdin/stdout/stderr), assuming your environment's locale is UTF8-based. Finally, to also treat _source_ code as UTF8, use the `use utf8;` pragma.

Comment: `perl -Mutf8 -CSDL -e '...'` allows to consume/output UTF-8 *as well* as use UTF-8 literals inside `-e` e.g. for a poor man's case folder: `perl -Mutf8 -CASDL -pe 'y/āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ/aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuüüüüAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUÜÜÜÜ/'`

Answer (score 2):

You also want to say, that strings in your code are utf-8. See [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default). So set not only `PERL_UNICODE=SDAL` but also `PERL5OPT=-Mutf8`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, finally got an solution to not put utf8::encode all over code. 
To synthesize and complete for other cases, like write and read files in utf8 and also works with LoadFile of an YAML file in utf8

```
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

open(FH, ">test.txt"); 
print FH "something éá";

use YAML qw(LoadFile Dump);
my $PUBS = LoadFile("cache.yaml");
my $f = "2917";
my $ref = $PUBS->{$f};
print "$f \"".$ref->{name}."\" ". $ref->{primary_uri}." ";
```

where cache.yaml is:

```
---
2917:
  id: 2917
  name: Semanário
  primary_uri: 2917.xml
```

Answer (score -3):

do in your shell:
$ env |grep LANG

This will probably show that your shell is not using a utf-8 locale.

Comment: Actually, it was set to utf-8. The problem was that I was outputting to STDOUT without setting binmode to utf-8;

Comment: This would be an orthogonal concern.  You need your Perl script to
output correct data before you can worry about how your terminal
emulator interprets it.