# How do I save a file as UTF-8 from Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8

I'm trying to create/save HTML files in Perl in UTF-8, but nothing I have done so far works. A [previous answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl) said to use binmode, so I tried that. Here is my code:

```
open (OUT, ">$sectionfilename");
binmode(OUT, ":utf8");
print OUT $section;
close OUT;
```

When I open these files in a text editor like Notepad they are still in ANSI encoding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want a BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: Do you mean exclusively Notepad? Because Notepad won't recognize UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: No, not exclusively Notepad, TextPad, too. The file is just not encoding as UTF-8.

Answer (score 19):

A text editor is a poor tool to examine low-level things such as encodings. Use a hexviewer/hexdumper instead. The modern way to write your example:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $sectionfilename;
print {$out} $section;
close $out;
```

[autodie](http://p3rl.org/autodie) enables automatic error-checking.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to work for me:

```
C:\Documents and Settings>cat a.pl
$sectionfilename = "a.txt";
$section = "Hello \x{263A}!\n";

open (OUT, ">$sectionfilename");
binmode(OUT, ":utf8");
print OUT $section;
close OUT;    

C:\Documents and Settings>perl a.pl

C:\Documents and Settings>file a.txt
a.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

But when I change the text to be written to:

```
$section = "Hello";
```

and run:

```
C:\Documents and Settings>perl a.pl

C:\Documents and Settings>file a.txt
a.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

Comment: That is because on simple text with characters < 128 there is no way to distinguish between ASCII and UTF-8 (bytes are the same). If you want `file` to show UTF-8 you need to force an UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) at file beginning between `open()` and `binmode()` with `print OUT "\x{ef}\x{bb}\x{bf}";`