# Reading an XML file with perl and XML::Simple, perl outputs non-english characters as hex

Tags: perl

I am trying to read an XML file, and output only a select number of fields however I have ran into two issues (which I think are related) which I have utterly failed at googling.

The XML file I am working with contains a lot of non-english characts, äöåéœ etc...

When I run print Dumper($data);
I get results like:

**Malbec Vi\x{f1}a Domingo F Sarmiento**

When I attempt to read through the XML and output specific fields, those hex symbols become questions marks:

**Malbec Vi?a Domingo F Sarmiento**

Any tips or at least a direction to go to for googling?

Code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;


# What file to use?
my $file = "systemet.xml";
# Read in the data
my $data = XMLin($file);
# Let's get some stuff!
foreach my $status (@{$data->{artikel}}) {
print $status->{namn} . "\n";
}
```

Thanks for any help and sorry if I sound a little ignorant, it's probably because I am.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl

Comment: You are officially one of my favorite people in the world!
Solved my problem immediately, thanks!

Comment: @bpg Perhaps you should put that in an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

and refer to this thread [How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)

Comment: As I said, that did the trick!

Now that that works it's on to next problem that crops up.

Comment: I agree Stew, I did not add it as an answer for you. I did it for the convenience of other SO users stumbling up on this thread searching for a quick solution. Also, to help them further, you should accept this answer. I imagine I'm trying to find a quick solution, I will be more confident if I find my solution as an accepted answer then as a comment.