# Wrong charset in Windows 7

Tags: character-encoding, decoding

I got a big problem. I save raport from ffmpeg.exe to *.log file.

In script I decode strinng from utf8 to windows1250 ( I'm from Poland and we had letter like "ą" or "ó").

This decode work perffectly in my Windows XP but in my friend computer not showing "ą" - showing "?". He have Windows 7.

Do you know how to make it work on all Windows? I really need code to work in all Windows machine.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

use [ked editor](http://www.dobreprogramy.pl/kED,Program,Windows,11810.html).

If you open file using it, press F4 and than you can select what type of coding do you want. It will remember your coding only if in file will be specials characters. Otherwise there is no point to keep and remember coding and again will be default

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is OK but i need do this in perl script. Cound you tell me why in Windows XP this charset works ok but in Windows 7 this decoding from UTF8 and encoding to CP1250 doesn't work?

Comment: Because you didnt declare coding and windows change it automatically to default (i think co). I dont know anything about perl, i though you are looking for editor. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)