# How can I get Perl to respect the locale encoding for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, without affecting file IO?

Tags: perl, encoding, locale

What is the best way to ensure Perl uses the locale encoding (as in LANG=en_US.UTF-8) for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, without affecting file IO?

If I use

```
use open ':locale';
say "mañana";
open (my $f, '>', 'test.txt'); say $f "mañana";
```

then the locale encoding is used for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, but also in test.txt, which is not very well-behaved: you don't want the encoding of a file to depend on the way you logged in.

Comment: What encoding do you expect in the output file?

Comment: [`export PERL_UNICODE=SAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[\_number/list\_]*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the encoding layers to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, you need to use

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
```

instead of

```
use open ':locale';
```

---

But that doesn't just add an encoding layer to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR; it causes the same layer to be added to file handles opened in scope by default. So we need to override that default with

```
open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $qfn)
```

or

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
```

---

All together:

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
open(my $fh_txt, '>',     $qfn);   # Text
open(my $fh_bin, '>:raw', $qfn);   # Binary
```

or

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
open(my $fh_txt, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $qfn);   # Text
open(my $fh_bin, '>:raw',             $qfn);   # Binary
```

Result:

```
my $s = chr(0xE9);

say         $s;      # U+E9 encoded as per locale
say $fh_txt $s;      # U+E9 encoded using UTF-8
say $fh_bin $s;      # Byte E9
```

(You can use `binmode($fh);` instead of `:raw` for binary files, if you prefer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
{ use open IO => ':locale'; }   # the IO => is optional
```

... does what the OP asked for.

The effect on subsequent opens is scoped, so putting the `use open ...`
in it's own little block prevents it from having any affect on file handles opened later.  `:locale` implies `:std` so it immediately modifies STDIN/OUT/ERR.