# Perl on Windows: Problems with Encoding

Tags: windows, perl, encoding, activeperl

I have a problem with my Perl scripts. In UNIX-like systems it prints out all Unicode characters like `ä` properly to the console. In the Windows commandline, the characters are broken to senseless glyphs. Is there a simple way to avoid this? I'm using `use utf8;`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl

Comment: Another question considering dispaly of unicode in windows console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: Hate-hate-hate-hate this `utf8` in lovely `Perl`

Comment: Perl's unicode is wonderful. Its the fact that it can't break backward compatibility to turn it on by default that I hate hate hate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`use utf8;` simply tells Perl your source is encoded using UTF-8.

It's not working on unix either. There are some strings that won't print properly (`print chr(0xE9);`), and most that do will print a "Wide character" warning (`print chr(0x2660);`). You need decode your inputs and encode your outputs.

In unix systems, that's usuaully

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

In Windows system, you'll need to use `chcp` to find the console's character page. (437 for me.)

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp437)';  # Encoding used by console
use open IO => ':encoding(cp1252)';   # Encoding used by files
```

Comment: Trying this out in Windows 7 cmd.exe, it only produced errors. `Odd number of elements in hash assignment at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/encoding.pm line 120. encoding: Unknown encoding ':std' at C:\Users\Peter\perl\foo.pl line 9.` (same for `:encoding...` and `IO => ..`). What I finally got to work was changing the cmd.exe font to Lucida console, chcp 1252, then use `use encoding 'cp1252';` inside the script.

Comment: @TLP, Fixed. Should be `open`, not `encoding`. Never use `encoding`.

Comment: +1 That works. Wow, so much trouble over printing characters.