# Escaping URLs and UTF-8 in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8, escaping

I am trying to access an online API that returns an .xml from a Perl Script and it uses the Catalan alphabet:
à,é,è,í,ò,ó,ú,·,ç .

I am using Perl's URI::Escape, so a "MWE" (without the actual URL of the dictionary I am trying to access, just in case it is considered spam or whatever) of what I am trying to do would be

```
use LWP::Simple;
use URI::Escape;
use utf8;

my $word = <STDIN>;
$word = uri_escape_utf8($word);
my $xmlweb = get("http://www.urlofthedictionary.com/search?q=$word&format=text/xml");
```

It "works", i.e. no error shows up, but it does not work properly (no results for the word are given if it contains any of these special characters). For example if I write `país` then `uri_escape_utf8()` returns `pa%C2%A1s%0A` , but I have seen that if I copy that exact same string to the url in my navigator, then it searches `pais` (instead of `país`) giving no results, and even in the URL it gets "translated" to `pais`. If I just use `uri_escape()` then the website gives an error:
`Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`

This is driving me insane, I always have problems with encodings. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? If the dictionary's url is needed I will provide it, no problem with that.

Comment: Seems like a problem of the site itself... encoding seems proper. What exact site is that?

Comment: @FlashThunder [link](http://openthesaurus.softcatala.org/synonyme/search?q=prova&format=text/xml) for an example (prova would be the word searched here). I have just discovered that the site's escaping for í is %C3%AD instead of %C3%A1, is that another different encoding? utf-16 maybe? As you see there is no version tag.

Comment: C3.A1 is the UTF-8 of U+00E1, LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem 1. You forget to remove (`chomp`) the trailing newline (`%0A`).

---

Problem 2. `uri_escape_utf8` expects Unicode code points, but I don't think you provided that. You need to decode what you got from STDIN. You can use:

```
use encoding ':std', ':encoding(cp850)';
```

`850` was obtained from the output of `chcp`. It could be different for you.

---

```
$ perl -MURI::Escape=uri_escape_utf8 -E'
   say uri_escape_utf8 "pa\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE}n";
'
pa%C3%ADn
```

Comment: this seems to be an answer

Comment: I see, I did not remove it because it worked with words without accents (for example prova%0A works). I have done it now but it still does not work, it appears that something may go wrong in the middle because it escapes í to %C3%A1 instead of %C3%AD . Maybe it has something to do with Strawberry Perl's encoding?

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much, this solved the encoding of the terminal but now I have problems with the encoding of the xml. I will read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224400/perl-on-windows-problems-with-encoding) that is related. Just one more question, is there any way to make this system-independent?

Comment: No. I'd write up a module, but noone's been able to tell me how to determine the encoding to use on unix machines.

Answer (score 1):

If I set `binmode(STDIN,'utf8')` before reading from STDIN and also make sure that my terminal sends also UTF8, then I get the correct encoding `%C3%AD`.

Comment: This might be the problem, the terminal. Is there any way to know the encoding used by my Strawberry Perl?

Comment: I think the other answer correctly guessed that you are on windows and showed a way to get your code page there.

Comment: Wasn't a guess. Strawberry Perl is a Perl distribution for Windows.

Comment: Sure, but nothing in you question showed that you are using Strawberry Perl.