# Perl in-place editing messes up text encoding

Tags: regex, perl

The input content is a chunk of html copied from webkit window, like

[image]

It's displayed correctly in web-kit using UTF-8.

What I want to do is to replace all the  tags, I use this one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe "s/<img.+?>//g"
```

The input is the richtext I copied to my clipboard and redirected into this one-liner by another program, probably it's something like:

```
echo "rich html text" | perl -i -pe "s/<img.+?>//g"
```

Well, it does remove the `<img>` tags, but all the Unicode characters get corrupted after substitution.

[image]

I am on Windows 7, locale En - US. The cmd codepage has already been set to UTF-8.
It doesn't work even if I pass the `-C` option.

Is there a way to keep the code as one-liner while make it working for Unicode input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/627661/725418

Comment: Instead of perl, output to stdout or a file to be sure this is not your first program which messes the content at first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting this in your perl one liner:

```
use open ":encoding(utf8)";
```

You can probably add it via -M:

```
perl -Mopen=:encoding(utf8) -i -pe "s/<img.+?>//g"
```

(Thanks to @TLP for reminding me of the syntax).

See also [the open pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)

Comment: The switch syntax for that line would be `-Mopen=:encoding(utf8)`

Comment: I forgot to mention, the input is not a file, it's the text I copied into my clipboard and piped into this one-liner by another program. I tried this `perl -i -pe "use open ':encoding(utf8)'; s/<img.+?>//g"`, it doesn't even do the replacement, I don't know where is wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

`perl -COE -i -pe "s/<img.+?>//g" input` should work, the `-COE` option turns on unicode on both STDIN and STDOUT.

See `perldoc perlrun` for more details.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried all the -C options. makes no differences.

Comment: even -CD?  I realized that you weren't working on STDIN/STDOUT, but rather on a file.