# How to make the output from Text::CSV utf8?

Tags: perl, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a CSV file, say win.csv, whose text is encoded in windows-1252. First I use iconv to make it in utf8.

```
$iconv -o test.csv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 win.csv
```

Then I read the converted CSV file with the following Perl script (utfcsv.pl).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use utf8;
use Text::CSV;
use Encode::Detect::Detector;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => ';',});
open my $fh, "<encoding(utf8)", "test.csv";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
  my $line = join " ", @$row;
  my $enc = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($line);
  print "($enc) $line\n";
}

$csv->eof || $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
$csv->eol("\r\n");
exit;
```

Then the output is like the following.

```
(UFT-8) .........
() .....
```

Namely the encoding of all lines are detected as UTF-8 (or ASCII). But the actual output does not seem to be UTF-8. In fact, if I save the output on a file

```
$./utfcsv.pl > output.txt
```

then the encoding of output.txt is detected as windows-1252.

**Question: How can I get the output text in UFT-8?**

Notes:

1. Environment: openSUSE 13.2 x86_64, perl 5.20.1
2. I do not use Text::CSV::Encoded because the installation fails. (Because test.csv is converted in UTF-8, so it is strange to use Text::CSV::Encoded.)
3. I use the following script to check the encoding. (I also use it to find out the encoding of the initial CSV file win.csv.)

.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Encode::Detect::Detector;
open my $in,  "<","$ARGV[0]" || die "open failed";
while (my $line = <$in>) {
  my $enc = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($line);
  chomp $enc;
  if ($enc) {
    print "$enc\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your text contain any character outside ASCII? It yes, it should be no problem to determine the real encoding. Otherwise the encoding detector gives arbitary results.

Comment: Yes. I am dealing with a German text which contains a lot of ü.

Comment: Try the top answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl -- I'm pretty sure that'll fix this for you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have set the encoding of the input file handle (which, by the way, should be `<:encoding(utf8)` -- note the colon) but you haven't specified the encoding of the *output* channel, so Perl will send unencoded character values to the output

The Unicode values for characters that will fit in a single byte -- Basic Latin (ASCII) between 0 and 0x7F, and Latin-1 Supplement between 0x80 and 0xFF -- are very similar to Windows code page 1252. In particular a small letter u with a diaresis is 0xFC in both Unicode and CP1252, so the text will look like CP1252 if it is output unencoded, instead of the two-byte sequence 0xC3 0xBC which is the same codepoint encoded in UTF-8

If you use `binmode` on STDOUT to set the encoding then the data will be output correctly, but it is simplest to use the `open` pragma like this

```
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;
```

which will set the encoding for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, as well as any newly-opened file handles. That means you don't have to specify it when you open the CSV file, and your code will look like this

Note that I have also added `use strict` and `use warnings`, which are essential in any Perl program. I have also 
used `autodie` to remove the need for checks on the status of all IO operations, and I have taken advantage of the way Perl interpolates arrays inside double quotes by putting a space between the elements which avoids the need for a `join` call

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => ';' });

open my $fh, '<', 'test.csv';

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    print "@$row\n";
}

close $fh;
```