# Printing to a file vs printing to shell in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I am writing a Perl program to convert my local language ASCII characters to Unicode characters (Tamil).

This is my program

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use open ':std';
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use Encode qw( encode decode );
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

Getopt::Long::Configure qw(gnu_getopt);

my $font;
my %map;
GetOptions(
    'font|f=s' => \$font,
    'help|h'   => \&usage,
) or die "Try $0 -h for help";

print "Do you want to map $font? (y/n)";
chomp( my $answer = lc <STDIN> );

$font = lc( $font );
$font =~ s/ /_/;
$font =~ s/(.*?)\.ttf/$1/;

if ( $answer eq "y" ) {
    map_font();
}
else {
    restore_map();
}

foreach ( @ARGV ) {

    my $modfile = "$_";

    $modfile =~ s/.*\/(.*)/uni$1/;

    process_file( $_, $modfile );
}

sub process_file {

    my @options = @_;

    open my $source, '<', "$options[0]";
    my $result = $options[1];
    my $test   = "./text";
    my $missingchar = join( "|", map( quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %map ) );

    while ( <$source> ) {
        $/ = undef;
        s/h;/u;/g;       #Might need change based on the tamil font
        s/N(.)/$1N/g;    #Might need change based on the tamil font
        s/n(.)/$1n/g;    #Might need change based on the font
        s/($missingchar)/$map{$1}/g;

        print "$_";

        open my $final, '>:utf8', "$result";
        print $final "$_";
        close $final;
    }
}

sub map_font {

    my @oddhexes = qw/0B95 0B99 0B9A 0B9E 0B9F 0BA3 0BA4 0BA8 0BAA 0BAE 0BAF 0BB0 0BB2 0BB5 0BB3 0BB4 0BB1 0BA9/;
    my @missingletters = qw/0BC1 0BC2/;
    my @rest = qw/0B85 0B86 0B87 0B88 0B89 0B8A 0B8E 0B8F 0B90 0B92 0B93 0B83  0BBE  0BBF  0BC0  0BC6  0BC7  0BC8  0BCD  0B9C  0BB7  0BB8  0BB9 0BCB 0BCA 0BCC/;

    foreach ( @oddhexes ) {

        my $oddhex = $_;

        $_ = encode( 'utf8', chr( hex( $_ ) ) );
        print "Press the key for $_   :";
        chomp( my $bole = <STDIN> );
        if ( $bole eq "" ) {
            next;
        }

        $map{$bole} = $_;

        foreach ( @missingletters ) {

            my $oddchar = encode( 'utf8', chr( hex( $oddhex ) ) . chr( hex( $_ ) ) );

            print "Press the key for $oddchar   :";
            chomp( my $missingchar = <STDIN> );
            if ( $missingchar eq "" ) {
                next
            }

            $map{$missingchar} = $oddchar;
        }

    }

    foreach ( @rest ) {

        $_ = encode( 'utf8', chr( hex( $_ ) ) );

        print "Press the key for $_   :";
        chomp( my $misc = <STDIN> );
        if ( $misc eq "" ) {
            next
        }

        $map{$misc} = $_;
    }

    open my $OUTPUT, '>', $font || die "can't open file";
    print $OUTPUT dump( \%map );
    close $OUTPUT;
}

sub restore_map {

    open my $in, '<', "$font" || die "can't open file: $!";

    {
        local $/;
        %map = %{ eval <$in> };
    }

    close $in;
}

sub usage {
    print "\nUsage: $0 [options] {file1.txt file2.txt..} \neg: $0 -f TamilBible.ttf chapter.txt\n\nOptions:\n  -f --font - used to pass font name\n  -h --help - Prints help\n\nManual mapping of font is essential for using this program\n";
    exit;
}
```

In subroutine `process_file`, output of `print "$_";` displays proper Tamil Unicode characters in the [terminal](http://pastebin.com/kC2ZwK1y).

However the [output to the file handle](http://pastebin.com/jZpLiPZ1) `$final` is very different.

The `%map` is [here](http://pastebin.com/m4QkjaLZ).

Why are the outputs different?

How can I correct this behaviour?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl) but this is not the same. In my case the terminal displays the result correctly while the filehandle output is different.

Comment: You should consider using *statement modifiers* such as `next if if $misc eq ""` instead of `if ( $misc eq "" ) { next }`

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the tip. I will modify the code

Comment: ASCII does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: I know that, I do not know much about encoding. I just wanted to convert whatever type of encoding to UNICODE. @SinanÜnür

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your open statement

```
open my $final, '>:utf8', "$result";
```

sets your file handle to expect characters, and to encode into UTF-8 sequences then on the way out. But you are sending it pre-encoded byte sequences from the `%map` hash, which causes those bytes to be treated as character and encoded *again* by Perl IO

In contrast, your terminal is set to expect UTF-8-encoded data, but `STDOUT` isn't set to do any encoding at all (`use open ':std'` has no effect on its own, see below) so it passes your UTF-8-encoded bytes through unchanged which happens to be what the terminal expects

By the way, you have set a default open mode of `:encoding(UTF-8)` for input and output streams with

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)'
```

but have overridden it in your call to `open`. The `:utf8` mode does a very basic translation from wide characters to byte sequences, but `:encoding(UTF-8)` is far more useful because it checks that each character being printed is a valid Unicode value. There is a good chance that it would have caught a mistake like this, and it would have been better to allow the default and write just

```
open my $final, '>', $result;
```

To keep things clean and tidy, your program should work in *characters*, and the file handles should be set to encode those characters to UTF-8 when those characters are printed

You can set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all newly-opened file handles as well as `STDIN` and `STDOUT` by adding

```
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;
```

to the top of your program (`:encoding(utf-8)` is preferable to `:utf8`) and remove *all* calls to `encode`. You had it almost right, but the `:std` and `:encoding(utf-8)` need to be in the same `use` statement

You should also add

```
use utf8;
```

at the very top so that you can use UTF-8 characters in the program itself

You also have a few incidental errors. For instance

- In the statement

  ```
  open my $in, '<', "$font" || die "can't open file: $!";
  ```

  it is almost always wrong to quote a single scalar variable like `$font` unless it happens to be an object and you want to invoke the stringification method

  You need `or` instead of `||`, otherwise you're just testing the truth of `$font`

  If I asked you what a variable called `$in` might contain I think you'd be hesitant; `$in_fh` is better and is a common idiom

  It's always nice to put the *name* of the file into the `die` string as well as the *reason* from `$!`

  Taking all of those into account makes your statement look like this

  ```
  open my $in_fh, '<', $font or die qq{Unable to open "$font" for input: $!};
  ```
- You should be consistent between upper and lower case scalar variables, and lower case is the correct choice. So

  ```
  open my $OUTPUT, '>', $font || die "can't open file";
  ```

  should be something like

  ```
  open my $out_fh, '>', $font or die qq{Unable to open "$font" for output: $!};
  ```
- The line

  ```
  $/ = undef;
  ```

  should be `local $/` as you have used elsewhere, otherwise you are permanently modifying the input record separator for the rest of your program and modules. It also appears *after* the first read from the file handle, so your program will read and process one line, and then the whole of the rest of the file in the next iteration of the `while` loop

Comment: Thank you so much!! You pointed out all the other things I was wondering about too.

Comment: @OneFace: Great. Have you managed to get it working without any of the `encode` calls?

Comment: I am re-checking the code right now. I have to re-map the font as the values of characters are very different when using `:std :encoding(utf-8)`. I am still enlarging the program adding various options. I will post the result once I re-map. Right now it's time for bed. Thank you once again for the extremely valuable help!

Comment: I was able to display the characters correctly in the terminal to get the font mapped. So the encoding works as you suggested

Comment: @OneFace: Excellent. Good night to Sri Lanka (?)