# How can I print non-English characters to the terminal?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

```
my $star = 'इस परीक्षण के लिए है';
```

I want to print this string as it is using encoding.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? If the terminal handles UTF8, you should be able to print the variable to STDOUT. See [How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)

Comment: i am using linux terminal and windows terminal

Answer (score 4):

You need the statement

```
use utf8;
```

at the top of your program to tell perl that the script is encoded in UTF-8. You can also write

```
use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;
```

to make UTF-8 the default output encoding

Your terminal must be expecting UTF-8 output. On Linux you should check the `LC_TYPE` environment variable

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

This should normally be `UTF-8` but you can change it if not

On Windows this is done with *code pages*. [For UTF-8 you need code page 65001](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use the `chcp` command to check and alter it

Now, provided your terminal is using a font that covers the characters you want to display, you should be able to just `print $star` to have the text appear on your terminal

Comment: +1 It should be noted that, if using `cmd.exe` on Windows, you are going to run into [problems](https://www.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-ouput-from-perl-and-c-programs-in.html). Setting `STDOUT` to use the [`:unix` layer](https://www.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-output-from-perl-in-cmdexe-layers.html) seems to help. Using a console container such as [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) will mask the problems, and file output will work fine. Also, with `cmd.exe` console set to code page 65001, keyboard input will not work properly. etc etc.