# UTF8 output from Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8, cygwin

I have a text file `test.txt` with the UTF8 encoded content `äöü` (these are German umlauts and just an example, the file size is 6 Bytes). I also have a Cygwin terminal on a Windows 10 PC with the correct LANG settings:

```
$ cat test.txt
äöü
```

I'd like to print the content of this file with a Perl script, but can't get it to work.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'test.txt';
print <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

results in

```
$ perl test.pl
├ñ├Â├╝
```

I tried all variations I found at [How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl) - none of them solved my problem. What's wrong?

EDIT per request:

```
$ file test.txt
test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators

$ echo $LANG
```

I also tried setting LANG to `de_DE.UTF-8`.

EDIT to narrow down the problem: If I try this with the Perl version 5.32.1 included in *Cygwin*, it works as expected. It still doesn't work in *Strawberry* Perl version 5.32.1. So it's probably no Perl problem nor a Windows problem nor something with language or encoding settings, it's a Strawberry Perl problem.

Comment: It works for me. So there is an `encoding` issue at your side. What is the output of `file test.txt` and of `echo $LANG` ? if you identify the encodings you can use `iconv` for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I edited my question and added the results from your commands.

Comment: What do the following 3 commands give you: od -t x1 test.txt; cat test.txt | od -t x1; perl test.pl | od -t x1

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It gives three times "0000000 c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc". The output of the script seams to be OK, but `cat test.txt` works, `perl test.pl` doesn't.

Comment: It works fine for me from the Cygwin terminal window  if I add `binmode(STDOUT,':encoding(utf-8)')` as suggested in the answer by @AnFi (and also add the `encoding(utf-8)` on the input file handle.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: This still gives me `├ñ├Â├╝`. Which perl version and which perl environment did you use?

Comment: @André perl version 5.30.3 installed from the Cygwin `perl` package and installed into `/usr/bin/perl`. Btw `od  -c test.txt` shows the same as in the answer by @matzeri

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I tried this and it worked. I also tried the Cygwin Perl version 5.32.1 and this works too. But with the Strawberry Perl version 5.32.1 it doesn't work. So, it's no Perl problem nor a Windows problem - it's a problem of the Strawberry environment. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a `cmd.exe` window or in `PowerShell`, you can change the codepage to 65001:

```
chcp 65001
```

If you do not want to change the codepage find out what `chcp` (or `"cp".Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP()`) returns and encode to that encoding.

```
use Encode;

open my $fh, '<:utf8','test.txt';
while(<$fh>){
    print encode('cp850',$_); # needs a recent Encode to support cp850
};
close $fh;
```

If you are in cygwin bash, you can call `chcp` with `system()` like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

system("chcp 65001 > NUL");

open my $fh, '<:utf8','test.txt';
while(<$fh>){   
    print encode('utf8',$_); # needs a recent Encode to support cp850
};
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. `chcp` works for cmd indeed. I'm still looking for a solution for the cygwin bash. With a bash at a Linux machine it works out of the box, but it doesn't at Windows.

The second solution changes the output encoding to cp850, but only a few unicode characters can be mapped to cp850. It works for the umlauts in my example above, but my real script uses many different characters.

Comment: If I call `cmd /c chcp 65001` from within a bash, it works in the bash too. This still looks like an ugly workaround ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the LANG setting

```
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

$ echo $LANG
de_DE.UTF-8

$ cat test.txt
äöü

$ perl test.pl
äöü

$ file test.txt
test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ od -c  test.txt
0000000 303 244 303 266 303 274  \n
0000007

$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: I tried this already. I get exactly the same output after executing your command - except for `perl test.pl`. It's crazy.

Comment: what terminal are you using ? And  are you sure of perl ?

Comment: I use the Cygwin bash, but also tried the bash inside "Windows Terminal", I tried "cmd.exe" and the "Windows PowerShell". I'm sure about the output of the perl script.

The PC itself is only a few days old and setup without any very special software. Beside this, I'm using Strawberry perl (strawberryperl.com).

Comment: No, I'm used to use Strawberry, because I can install all required packages there easily. I tried my script on a Linux machine now and it works as expected. This is probably no Perl problem but a Windows problem. On the other side: cat test.txt works ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ "$( cygpath 'C:\progs\sp5302-x64\perl\bin\perl.exe' )" -M5.010 -e'
   use Win32;
   BEGIN {
      Win32::SetConsoleCP(65001);
      Win32::SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
   }
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   say chr(0x2660);
'
♠
```

(`` BEGIN { `chcp 65001` } `` would also have done the trick.)

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly define encoding of input and output.

```
open( my $fh, '<:utf8', 'test.txt');
binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');
print <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already without success.